# If my masters and PhD subjects are different can I become an assistant professor?

Tags: phd, job-search, assistant-professor, masters-post-phd

I'm currently doing my M.Sc in Physics and want to do Phd in Atmospheric Physics or Environmental sciences. Am I eligible to become an assistant professor of Physics?

Answer (score 3):

In my experience in the U.K., applications for assistant professorships in general focus on things like research output and teaching. They almost certainly do not care what you did your masters in.

I can’t promise that other universities in different countries wouldn’t have some obscure rule about this, but it seems unlikely to me.

Answer (score 1):

You generally become Assistant Professor in an area very close to your research subject, because professorship are often given on the basis of the research output.

Teaching-related skills and experience are generally required, but you generally obtain them as a side "gig" during your research years (PhD and Postdoc, for example) ... so they tend to be close to your research topic.

Outside of the scope of your Master's exams (and not even there), do not think in terms of bureaucratic, closed boxes. A PhD in Atmospheric Physics can range from "physics" as investigating [high-energy particles](https://gmd.copernicus.org/articles/11/4515/2018/)  to "arts" as in [data-science integrated into arts](https://acp.copernicus.org/articles/14/2987/2014/acp-14-2987-2014.html).

It depends on your specific person if you are the "physicist doing physics" borrowed to "atmospheric physics" or the "atmospheric physicist" borrowing "physics" technique ... in the end no one cares, as long as the results are consistent and relevant to the community.